# Move files to specific directory, according to file extension

Tags: python, performance, beginner, file-system

I've written the following script

```
import shutil,os,glob

# setting up destination folders

PYDEST = "/home/ubuntu/python-scripts/python-test"

TEXTDEST = "/home/ubuntu/python-scripts/texte-test"

def move8files(pwd):
    PWD = pwd + "*"
    for files in glob.glob(PWD):
        if files.endswith(".txt"):
            print(files)
            shutil.move(files,TEXTDEST)
        elif files.endswith(".py"):
            shutil.move(files,PYDEST)

move8files("/home/ubuntu/python-scripts/")
```

Questions/Issues are the following:

- How can I make it simpler, especially by using the `os.listdir` but with having the pathname (`listdir` does not give pathname)?
- Would it be possible to include a part in my script, where instead of saying which folders are for python or text files, it will look syntaxically at specific folders containing words like `python` or `texte` in it?
- What can I improve in my script, for better performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea, how to make it *simpler*. I could only offer an alternative:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import shutil

fullpath = os.path.join
python_directory = "./py"
start_directory = "./mixed"
text_files = "./txt"


def main():
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            source = fullpath(dirname, filename)
            if filename.endswith("py"):
               shutil.move(source, fullpath(python_directory, filename))
            elif filename.endswith("txt"):
                shutil.move(source, fullpath(text_files, filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think `os.walk()`is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @thomas-junk, thanks for your feedback. Why did you use `def main()`?  And what is  `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

Comment: Python files could be run in two modes: 1) they could be run on their own; then ___name___ is set to "___main___" or 2) they could (accidentally) be imported. And to prevent the interpreter to blindly run any code nonintentionally, you guard against that with the guarding clause if ___name___ == " ___main___ ", read: _if you are running in standalone mode, run `main()`_.

Comment: I messed up "dunder" in my comment above (thanks markdown :D). But you see, what I meant.

Comment: No worries @thomas-junk, I got your point ;)

Comment: that os walk stuff is just great!!!

Comment: one more question: The `main()` is coming back often. I'm tempted to use it but let's say I have several functions: Should I still use it and if yes, how?

Comment: No problem. Define your functions as you like and call them in any order in main(). This is no different than say _int main(int argc, **char argv)_ in _C_ or _public static void main()_ in _Java_

Answer (score 2):

Expanding @ThomasJunk's answer I think you can improve a bit by using a small dictionary, so you can add more file types if you need to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import shutil

fullpath = os.path.join
python_directory = "./py"
start_directory = "./mixed"
text_files = "./txt"

default_path = "./default"

dir_lookup = {
    'py': './py/',
    'txt': './txt/'
}

def get_extension(filename):
    return filename[filename.rfind('.')+1:]

def main():
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            source = fullpath(dirname, filename)
            extension = get_extension(filename)
            if (extension in dir_lookup):
                shutil.move(source, fullpath(dir_lookup[extension], filename))
            else:
                shutil.move(source, fullpath(default_path, filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, a side note: you're working with relative paths, so be careful, you should add a few checks.

For example I would add a check to see that the destination directory actually exists.

I would also add a check that the directories are what they seem. If one or more of the destination directories is actually a link to another directory or even worse to a file, you may end up overwriting stuff.

EDIT: As suggested, I added a default case when there is no match in the dictionary. Checking that the key exists is one way, and it's probably good enough for such a simple program. Another way would be to use `defaultdict`, but I didn't want to make it too complicated.

Comment: and what happens with `.pdf`?

Comment: @ThomasJunk You're right, I can add a default case

Comment: Hi @ChatterOne, what's the purpose of `get_extension()`?

Comment: @AndyK `get_extension()` gets the extension of the filename. You could also not have the function and inline it, I just though it was easier to read.

Comment: @ChatterOne I got the logic. Thanks. Bit tricky but it is interesting

Comment: @ChatterOne you know `os.path.splitext()`?

Comment: Besides you could use `dict.get('$value', '$default')`. No if clause needed

Comment: @ThomasJunk yes, I know, but you can post another answer with everything combined together if you want, there's no point in keeping editing an answer :-)

Comment: @ChatterOne one more question: Can you explain a bit more about this `return filename[filename.rfind('.')+1:]`?

Comment: @AndyK: to find the extension of the file what you want is to get everything from the last `.` up to the end. So, you find the last occurence of `.` with `rfind` and starting from there you get the rest of the string. You add `+1` so that the `.` itself will not be there.